# higlight typed character in ajax autoextender textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I am using AJAX Auto Extender, what i want is when i press "a" then all a in populated list become yellow or any other color.

below is my code:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCourse" runat="server" Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoExtend" runat="server" CompletionInterval="100"
            CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="txtCourse" MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServicePath="~/courseprovider.asmx"
            OnClientItemSelected="OnContactSelected" ServiceMethod="getcoursedetail">
        </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Please Help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

ADD in

```
  <CC1:AutoCompleteExtender ID = autoextender CompletionListCssClass="completionListElement"
   CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="AutoComplete_ListItemHilite"  CompletionListItemCssClass="listItem" 
   OnClientPopulated="ClientPopulated" ></CC1:AutoCompleteExtender >
```

---

CSS CLASS

---

```
   .completionListElement
    {
       list-style-type:none;
        margin:0px 0px 0px 1px;
       padding:0px;
       border:1px solid #cecece;
       background-color:#efefef;
       box-shadow:0px 3px 6px 0px #B8B8B8;
       cursor:pointer;
    }        
    .listItem
    {
       list-style-type:none; 
       padding:5px;
    }        


    .AutoComplete_ListItemHilite
  {
   color: #4B4B4B; padding:5px;  background-color:#cecece;
  }
   .AutoComplete_ListItemHiliteText
  {
   color: #ce0000;  font-weight:bold;
   }
```

---

ADD JAVASCRIPT

---

```
    function ClientPopulated(source, args) {
        if (source._currentPrefix != null) {
            var list = source.get_completionList();

            var search = source._currentPrefix.toLowerCase();

            for (var i = 0; i < list.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var text = list.childNodes[i].innerHTML;
                var index = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(search);
                if (index != -1) {
                    var value = text.substring(0, index);
                    value += '<span class="AutoComplete_ListItemHiliteText">';
                    value += text.substr(index, search.length);
                    value += '</span>';
                    value += text.substring(index + search.length);
                    list.childNodes[i].innerHTML = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

AND ADD THIS ONE in your Javascript OnContactSelected()

ADD THIS ONE --->

```
      function OnContactSelected(source, e) {
        source.get_element().value = (document.all) ? e._item.innerText : e._item.textContent;
        var str = $('#<%=txtCourse.ClientID %>').val();
```